# Ant: Conditionally adding resources

Tags: ant

I have a requirement where I need to add certain resources to the 'resources' set only if they are available. I was trying to add  within the resources which ant does not like. Ant does not allow conditional statements in the  tag.

```
<resources>
    <if>
    ..
    </fi>
</resources>
```

Any suggestions/ideas? Please note I do not want to use 'erroronmissingdir' attribute in the fileset tag as I do not want the ant call to fail in all the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#restrict), there is already way to restrict to only existing resources using the `<exist>` element. Try something like:

```
<project xmlns:rsel="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors">
  ...    
   <restrict>
       <resources>
       ...
       </resources>
       <rsel:exists />
    </restrict>
```

Comment: This looks promising although I would have to modify our custom ant tasks to accept such resources (currently uses a Union). I will give this a try in a few days time.